# Generating classes from XSD file

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I'm trying to generate Java classes from [spring-beans.xsd](http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd) by using JAXB (training purposes only) and I've got this error:

```
parsing a schema...
[ERROR] Property "Ref" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.
  line 582 of file:/C:/spring-beans.xsd

[ERROR] The following location is relevant to the above error
  line 622 of file:/C:/spring-beans.xsd

[ERROR] Property "Value" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.
  line 584 of file:/C:/spring-beans.xsd

[ERROR] The following location is relevant to the above error
  line 629 of file:/C:/spring-beans.xsd

[ERROR] Property "Key" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.
  line 1135 of file:/C:/spring-beans.xsd

[ERROR] The following location is relevant to the above error
  line 1138 of file:/C:/spring-beans.xsd

[ERROR] Property "Ref" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.
  line 1052 of file:/C:/spring-beans.xsd

[ERROR] The following location is relevant to the above error
  line 1071 of file:/C:/spring-beans.xsd

[ERROR] Property "Value" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.
  line 1054 of file:/C:/spring-beans.xsd

[ERROR] The following location is relevant to the above error
  line 1078 of file:/C:/spring-beans.xsd

Failed to parse a schema.
```

What's wrong? Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You want us to tell you what's wrong with your schema without seeing the schema? We're not mind-readers.

Comment: Click the link.

Comment: So it's a valid schema that your JAXB software can't handle. Sorry, I don't know JAXB well enough to help you.

Comment: Well, thanks for trying, anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in each case you have two XML items - an element like

```
<xsd:element ref="ref"/>
```

and an attribute like

```
<xsd:attribute name="ref" type="xsd:string"/>
```

in the same complex type. They both map by default to properties named `Ref`. But since these two XML items are different things, JAXB complains about naming conflict.

The solution is normally quite simple (and actually suggested by the error log).
Customize one of the properties using `jaxb:property` binding. Something along the lines:

```
<jaxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <jaxb:bindings 
        schemaLocation="spring-beans.xsd" 
        node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:bindings node="xs:element[@name='constructor-arg']/xs:complexType/xs:attribute[@name='ref']">
            <jaxb:property name="aRef"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```